# 1's complement checksum even bit errors

Tags: networking, udp, checksum

I am trying to wrap my head around 1's complement checksum error detection as is used in UDP.

My understanding with simplified example for an UDP-like 1's complement checksum error checking algorithm operating on 8 bit words (I know UDP uses 16 bit words):

1. Sum all 8 bit words of data, carry the MSB rollover to the LSB.
2. Take 1's complement of this sum, set checksum, send datagram
3. Receiver adds with carry rollover all received 8 bit words of data in the incoming datagram, adds checksum.
4. If sum = 0xFF, no errors. Else, error occurred, throw away packet.

It is obvious that this algorithm can detect 1 bit errors and by extension any odd-numbered bit errors. If just one bit in an 8-bit data word is corrupted, the sum + checksum will never equal 0xFF. A plain and simple example would be A = 00000000, B = 00000001, then ~(A + B) = 11111110. If A(receiver) = 00000001, B(reciever) = 00000001, the sum + checksum would be 0x00 != 0xFF

My question is:

It's not too clear to me if this can detect 2 bit errors. My intuition says no, and a simple example is taking A = 00000001, B = 00000000, then sum + checksum would be 0xFF, but there are two total errors in A and B from sender to receiver. If the 2 bit error occurred in the same word, theres a chance it could be detected, but it doesn't seem guaranteed.

How robust is UDP error checking? Does it work for even numbers of bit errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some even-bit changes can be detected, some can't.

Any error that changes the sum will be detected.  So a 2-bit error that changes the sum will be detected, but a 2-bit error that does not change the sum will not be detected.

A 2-bit error in a single word (single byte in your simplified example) will change the value of that word, which will change the sum, and therefore will always be detected.  Most 2-bit errors across different words will be detected, but a 2-bit error that changes the same bit in different directions (one 0->1, the other 1->0) in different words will not change the sum -- the change in value created by one of the changed bits will be cancelled out by the equal-but-opposite change in value created by the other changed bit -- and therefore that error will not be detected.

Because this checksum is simply an addition, it will also fail to detect the insertion or removal of words whose arithmetic value is zero (and since this is a one's complement computation, that means words whose content is all 0s *or* all 1s).

It will also fail to detect transpositions of words, (because a+b gives the same sum as b+a), or more generally it will fail to detect errors that add the same amount to one word as they subtract from the other (because a+b gives the same sum as (a+n)+(b-n), e.g. 3+3=4+2=5+1).  You could consider the transposition and cancelling-error cases to be made up of multiple pairs of same-bit changes.